# Web Scraping table in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, data-science

I need to scrape table from the [here](https://foodb.ca/foods/FOOD00615)

Only table of Composition

Headers

1. compound
2. Structure(Only if can)
3. Content Range
4. average
5. reference

All the rows of entries should be include

Comment: Any code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

just access this table using table id = DataTables_Table_0
then save all the rows as a list and then access these lists one by one to access each column.
save the values in separate lists and create a 2D list that will be fed into your dataframe.

Use Beautiful soup and pandas.

Comment: when you scrap you get the html code. if that code has no table than yes you will not get a table

Comment: sorry, actually there is the table in the html code but it its in the <script> tag which mean script loading data to html from directly from the database

Comment: try to check that the table data is present in HTML code or not. If the table is shown on web that means data must be their too. use script tag to find the information